# Where is the apache2 directory on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, apache2, authentication, etc, passwd

In order to activate the Basic Auth I installed apache2-utils:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y apache2-utils
```

but I can't find the /etc/apache2 directory. I uninstalled and reinstalled the package and I still can't find the location of the directory. However the command

```
htpasswd
```

is working. Do you have any ideas where the directory is located?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed apache2?

Comment: Thank you fot the answer!
No, but I thought this is installed along with utils? The documentation https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/ says I have to install apache2-utils (Debian, Ubuntu) or httpd-tools and then I should find the directory /etc/apache2 ?

Comment: `apache2-utils` can exist standalone to Apache2 the webserver.  Utils are not dependent on the Apache2 webserver itself to operate.

Comment: Nginx is an http-server by itself. I guess apache2 is only mentioned as an example. Because many people use apache2 as main http-server and nginx for load-balancing. It's worth to read more about this topic. Configuring a server is not an easy go, when your goal is to have a stable, performant and secure server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the package list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/apache2-utils/filelist), you will not have an `/etc/apache2` directory after installing the utilities. Oddly enough, you will need to install the web server itself, and probably reinstall the utilities to ensure things are properly aware of each other.

```
sudo apt install apache2
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-utils
```